# Flutter First of type design

Tags: flutter

On web, i use article **this css** to design the **first paragraph** of my content

```
p:first-of-type {font-weight: 600;}
```

How to **make same** on flutter ?

Thank for your help

Comment: provide ss or link to see your design

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your use case in many different ways one of them

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  final values = ['Apple', "Ball", "Cat"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            for (var index = 0; index < values.length; index++)
              if (index == 0)
                Text(
                  values[index],
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                )
              else
                Text(values[index])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```